# Storing XML text nodes into an array

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to store all of the text nodes of of the "directory" elements into an array of strings. I'm getting an empty array returned and I can't figure out why the array is empty.

Here's the XML

```
<config>
    <directories>
        <directory>directory1</directory>
        <directory>directory2</directory>
    </directories>
</config>
```

Here's the ruby code

```
require 'nokogiri'

directories = []
directories.each do |directory|
  directory = config.at('//config/directories').text
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're iterating over an empty array. The `directories` array you've created doesn't have any content, that's why when you assign to directory the content from the iteration you get an empty array too.

Try instead iterating over the parsed XML and then pushing, like:

```
xml_structure = <<-XML
<config>
  <directories>
    <directory>directory1</directory>
    <directory>directory2</directory>
  </directories>
</config>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_structure)
directories = []
doc.xpath('//config/directories/directory').each do |directory|
  directories.push directory.text
end
p directories
# ["directory1", "directory2"]
```

Or using map you can do it too:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_structure)
p doc.xpath('//config/directories/directory').map(&:text)
# ["directory1", "directory2"]
```